# Access object from hash map

Tags: java

My Hashmap as declared as `HashMap<String, ArrayList<SortableContactList>>` where `SortableContactList` list is a POJO class as

```
public class SortableContactList {
    private long id;
    private String displayName;
    private String homePhone;
    private String workPhone;
    private String mobilePhone;
    private String primaryEmail;
    private String tags;
         // Getters and Setters
}
```

Initializing my hashmap as

```
myHash.put(keyChar, arrayOfSortableContactList_objects)
```

My need is to get each attribute of an object which stored in arraylist. How can I make this.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that your hash value is an array of `SortableContactList`? Sounds strange to me. Do you perhaps simply want a `HashMap<String, SortableContactList>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you would need sth in the lines of `myHash.get("myKeyString").get(x).getHomePhone()` for individual attributes. The question remains, how to determine x, so maybe you should consider accepting the advice of MarcoS, implementing the `HashMap` as follows : `HashMap<String, SortableContactList>` 
And you should definitely consider implementing hashCode for your SortableContactList to ensure correct hashing , i.e. storing and retrieving the objects in a HashMap. For details please consult this [great advice from Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf)

**EDIT** : added MarcoS' advice of implemeting the HashMap as `HashMap<String, SortableContactList>`

Comment: `myHash.get("myKeyString")` returns an `arrayOfSortableContactList_objects`. Hence the OP needs to either put a single `SortableContactList` or iterate the array of such objects and get individual attributes.

Comment: I agree with the recommendation of implementing hashCode. However, the way pankaj described the data structure, `myHash.get("myKeyString")` would return an ArrayList, and so you can't directly call `getHomePhone()` on it!!!

Answer (score 0):

could not understand your question.
please elaborate some more.

Well there are 2 ways you can achieve sorting:

1. Implement Comparable interface in your SortableContactList class; implement the functioning for the method `compareTo()`. This interface helps you to change the natural ordering for `sort()` method.
2. If you want to sort using different attributes then you should implement `Comparator` interface containing the `compare(Object1,Object2)`
   here you can provide on what what basis you want to sort your object.

hope this is useful